# How to select first unique id for numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I want to search in DB first unique ID for numbers Im searching. Let's say im searching for numbers: 721, 969, 337. All of those numbers has atleast 3 entries in DB like:

```
id, number, name
1, 721, valueA
2, 721, valueB
3, 721, valueC
4, 969, valueD
5, 969, valueE
6, 969, valueF
7, 969, valueG
8, 337, valueH
9, 337, valueI
10, 337, valueJ
```

So i want to get id (could be lowest one but i don't mind) for each number 721(1), 969(4), 337(8). Any ideas, i could use separate queries for this but i hope there is solution using one?

Comment: if you don't mind which id you get why did you tagged the question with `greatest-n-per-group` ?  Also what in cases if you search for a number which does not exists in the table if that matters?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the minimum id per number:

```
SELECT number, MIN(id) id FROM mytable GROUP BY number
```

If you want the whole record:

```
SELECT id, number, name
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.number = t.number AND t1.id < t.id
)
```

Or, if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
SELECT id, number, name
FROM (
    SELECT t.* ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITON BY number ORDER by id) rn FROM mytable t
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: How would query 1 work as that is a invalid SQL query in general cases..   i assume it should be `GROUP BY number` also a `WHERE` seams to be missing to fllter out the search numbers.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I fixed the typo in the first query, thanks for spotting it!

Comment: No problem but still a `WHERE number IN(721, 969, 337)` would be needed for the queries if the topicstarter needs these number counts only i assume the real data not only containing these `721, 969, 33` numbers

Answer (score 1):

> So i want to get id (could be lowest one but i don't mind) for each
>   number 721(1), 969(4), 337(8). Any ideas, i could use separate queries
>   for this but i hope there is solution using one?

self (left) join on the same table with a filter might be the most logical approach assumming you need to have all columns.. 
More or less like the queries below.

**Query (min id)**

```
SELECT 
   table_1.id
 , table_1.number
 , table_1.name
FROM 
 t AS table_1
LEFT JOIN 
 t AS table_2
ON
   table_1.number = table_2.number 
 AND
   table_1.id > table_2.id 

 AND
   table_1.number IN(721, 969, 337)
WHERE
 table_2.id IS NULL
```

**Result**

```
| id  | number | name   |
| --- | ------ | ------ |
| 1   | 721    | valueA |
| 4   | 969    | valueD |
| 8   | 337    | valueH |
```

**Query (max id)**

```
SELECT 
   table_1.id
 , table_1.number
 , table_1.name
FROM 
 t AS table_1
LEFT JOIN 
 t AS table_2
ON
   table_1.number = table_2.number 
 AND
   table_1.id < table_2.id 

 AND
   table_1.number IN(721, 969, 337)
WHERE
 table_2.id IS NULL;
```

**Result**

```
| id  | number | name   |
| --- | ------ | ------ |
| 3   | 721    | valueC |
| 7   | 969    | valueG |
| 10  | 337    | valueJ |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dv89oQPqRBLt7LTnkvywfT/0)

If you only need to have the id, number columns data the query is more simple

**Query min and max id**

```
SELECT number, MIN(id) id FROM t WHERE number IN(721, 969, 337) GROUP BY number;

SELECT number, MAX(id) id FROM t WHERE number IN(721, 969, 337) GROUP BY number;
```

**Results**

```
**min**

| number | id  |
| ------ | --- |
| 337    | 8   |
| 721    | 1   |
| 969    | 4   |

**max**

| number | id  |
| ------ | --- |
| 337    | 10  |
| 721    | 3   |
| 969    | 7   |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dv89oQPqRBLt7LTnkvywfT/1)

**performance note** 
For performance all these queries needs to have a `index(number, id)` at minimal..

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using correlated subquery

```
 select * from tablename a
 where id in (select min(id) from tablename b where a.number=b.number)
```